# declaring string using pointer to int

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to initialize a string using pointer to int

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int *ptr = "AAAA";
   printf("%d\n",ptr[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

the result of this code is **1094795585**
could any body explain this behavior and why the code gave this answers ?

Comment: This is invoking undefined behaviour.  But why do you expect 65656565?

Comment: Change `int` to `char` and try again.

Comment: This code is ill-formed. If your compiler doesn't tell you this, then you need to figure out how to invoke your compiler in standard mode.

Comment: `-pedantic-errors` is your best friend.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth i expect 65656565 because every 'A' will be saved in a byte which has an ascii 65 and the pointer to int points to 4 bytes   , so ptr[0] will read the first 4 bytes , which the all have 65

Comment: Where does the 100 come from?  (i.e. 6565 = 65 + 65*100 ...)

Comment: Aren't you getting any warning for `int *ptr = "AAAA";` ?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it will concatenate them

Comment: @Dayalrai yes i get a warning

Comment: @MitatKoyuncu i know , i was wondering why this behavior will happen when using int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to initialize a string using pointer to int

The *string literal* `"AAAA"` is of type `char[5]`, that is array of five elements of type `char`.

When you assign:

```
int *ptr = "AAAA";
```

you actually *must* use explicit cast (as types don't match):

```
int *ptr = (int *) "AAAA";
```

But, still it's potentially invalid, as `int` and `char` objects may have different *alignment requirements*. In other words:

```
alignof(char) != alignof(int)
```

may hold. Also, in this line:

```
printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);
```

you are invoking *undefined behavior* (so it might print `"Hello from Mars"` if compiler likes so), as `ptr[0]` dereferences `ptr`, thus violating *strict aliasing rule*.

Note that it is valid to make transition `int * ---> char *` and read object as `char *`, but not the opposite.

---

> the result of this code is 1094795585

The result makes sense, but for that, you need to rewrite your program in valid form. It might look as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union StringInt {
    char s[sizeof("AAAA")];
    int n[1];
};

int main(void)
{
    union StringInt si;
    strcpy(si.s, "AAAA");

    printf("%d\n", si.n[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

To decipher it, you need to make some assumptions, depending on your implementation. For instance, if

- `int` type takes four bytes (i.e. `sizeof(int) == 4`)
- CPU has little-endian byte ordering (though it's not really matter, since every letter is the same)
- default character set is ASCII (the letter `'A'` is represented as `0x41`, that is `65` in decimal)
- implementation uses two's complement representation of signed integers

then, you may deduce, that `si.n[0]` holds in memory:

```
0x41 0x41 0x41 0x41
```

that is in binary:

```
01000001 ...
```

The sign (most-significant) bit is unset, hence it is just equal to:

```
65 * 2^24 + 65 * 2^16 + 65 * 2^8 + 65 =

65 * (2^24 + 2^16 + 2^8 + 1) = 65 * 16843009 = 1094795585
```

Answer (score 3):

`1094795585` is correct.

`'A'` has the ASCII value `65`, i.e. `0x41` in hexadecimal.

Four of them makes `0x41414141` which is equal to `1094795585` in decimal.

---

You got the value `65656565` by doing `65*100^0 + 65*100^1 + 65*100^2 + 65*100^3` but that's wrong since a byte<sup>1</sup> can contain 256 different values, not 100.

So the correct calculation would be `65*256^0 + 65*256^1 + 65*256^2 + 65*256^3`, which gives `1094795585`.

It's easier to think of memory in hexadecimal because one hexadecimal digit directly corresponds to half a byte<sup>1</sup>, so two hex digits is one full byte<sup>1</sup> (cf. `0x41`). Whereas in decimal, `255` fits in a single byte<sup>1</sup>, but `256` does not.

---

<sup>1</sup> assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`

Comment: It is only implementation defined because C does not imply ASCII character set, the size of an int is not defined by the standard (it used to be 16 bits and is now currently 32 or 64 bits). I won't speak of endianness because "AAAA" is symetric. You should say that this is correct on current 32 bit systems using ASCII (ok, those are the most common, but other used to exist and still could)

Comment: @SergeBallesta it's undefined because the code is ill-formed

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Indeed! I read it the wrong way : converting an int * to a char * is legal, but the opposite is only if you ensured there was no alignment problem : you are right is is UB

Comment: @SergeBallesta converting `int *` to `char *` without a cast is ill-formed

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I had already added the explicit cast in my own answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

65656565 this is a wrong representation of the value of "AAAA" you are seprately representing each character and "AAAA" is stored as array.Its converting into 1094795585  because  `%d` identifier prints decimal value. Run this in `gdb` with following command:

```
x/8xb (pointer)    //this will show you the memory hex value

x/d (pointer)     //this will show you the converted decimal value
```

Answer (score 0):

@zenith gave you the answer you expected, but your code invokes UB. Anyway, you could demonstrate the same in an almost correct way :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i, val;
   char *pt = (char *) &val; // cast a pointer to any to a pointer to char : valid
   for (i=0; i<sizeof(int); i++) pt[i] = 'A'; // assigning bytes of int : UB in general case
   printf("%d 0x%x\n",val, val);
   return 0;
}
```

Assigning bytes of an int is UB in the general case because C standard says that *[for] signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit*. And a remark adds *Some combinations of padding bits might generate trap representations, for example, if one padding
bit is a parity bit*.

But in common architectures, there are no padding bits and all bits values correspond to valid numbers, so the operation is valid (but implementation dependant) on all common systems. It is still implementation dependant because size of int is not fixed by standard, nor is endianness.

So : on a 32 bit system using no padding bits, above code will produce

```
1094795585 0x41414141
```

indepentantly of endianness.

Comment: The same would be on 64BIT too "1094795585 0x41414141"